Transformation of multi-variate probability densities using reciprocal of inverse function jacobian
If $x$ and $y$ are $d$-dimensional vectors. We transform probability densities $P_x(x)$ and $P_y(y)$ according to $x = g(y)$. Transform is given by $P_y(y) = P_x(x)|\det \mathbf{J}| = P_x(g(y))|\det \mathbf{J}| $. Where $J_{ij} = \frac{\partial{g_i}}{\partial{y_j}}$. Now let’s say I’m not given $x = g(y)$ but it’s inverse $y = f(x)$. Jacobian of $f$ is $\mathbf{J_f}$.
Would I simply do?:
$P_y(y) = f(P_x(x) \frac{1}{|\det \mathbf{J_f}|})$

No must use inverse. $P_y(y) = P_x(f^{-1}(y))\frac{1}{|\det \mathbf{J_f(f^{-1}(y))}|}$

Please add some details, a one-liner is not a good answer.
